# Accessing Properties of Properties in DataBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, properties

I have two public properties `Foo` and `Bar` in my ViewModel. `Foo` is just a string and `Bar` is a class that has a public property `Name` which is a string.

I want to bind `Bar.Name` to some GUI element. **How do I do that?**

`<Label Content="{Binding Foo}">` writes the string `Foo` into the Label, as expected.

But `<Label Content="{Binding Bar.Name}">` does not write the name of `Bar` into the Label. Instead, the Label stays empty.

EDIT:
The `DataContext` of my XAML (and thus, of the Label) is set to the ViewModel.

EDIT2: Of course, the real code is not as simple as described above. I built a minimal working example that only represents the above description:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyTestNamespace.MyXAML"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006">
    <StackPanel>
        <Label Content="{Binding Foo}"></Label>
        <Label Content="{Binding Bar.Name}"></Label> <!-- Works fine! -->
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace MyTestNamespace
{
    class MyVM
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }
        public MyBar Bar { get; set; }

        public MyVM()
        {
            Foo = "I am Foo.";
            Bar = new MyBar("I am Bar's name.");
        }
    }

    class MyBar
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public MyBar(string text)
        {
            Name = text;
        }
    }
}
```

This in fact DOES work as expected. Since I cannot share the actual code with you (too much and owned by company), I need to search for the cause on my own. Any hints on possible reasons are welcome!

Comment: Are you sure that the Name property of the Bar class instance in your viewmodel is filled (and the Bar property is instantiated correctly)? How is the DataContext set on your label (or one of the parents or the DataTemplate)?

Comment: Yes, everything is set up correctly. I can work normally with `Bar.Name` in the code. Neither `Bar` nor `Bar.Name` are null, ever.

Comment: Please share the code for more insight

Comment: is the value for `Name` set in the constructor of `Bar` or afterwards, if so do you raise the property changed event after the value is set ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Your Model.cs:

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Name"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
}
```

2.Your ViewModel:

```
  public MainViewModel()
  {
     _model = new Model {Name = "Prop Name" };  
  }



  private Model _model;
  public Model Model
  {
      get
      {
          return _model;
      }
      set
      {
          _model = value;     
      }
  }
```

3.Your View, with DataContext set to your ViewModel:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" 
    DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="{Binding Model.Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Vignesh N.'s comment I was able to solve the problem.

In the actual code `Bar` can change, but in the beginning it's name is an empty string. This is what the Label shows when the window is opened. Because the `Label` does not get notified when the `Bar` property changes, it does not update.

Solution: Make the ViewModel implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and define `Bar` like this:

```
private MyBar _bar;
public MyBar Bar
{
    get
    {
        return _bar;
    }

    set
    {
        if (_bar != value)
        {
            _bar = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Bar)));
        }
    }
}
```